# Why is hosting outside of IIS termed as self host?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In general, if a third service provider manages the web server for me then it is hosted, while if I am by myself managing the web server then it is self-hosting.

In ASP.NET Core, In both places, I am the one who publishes the code on the server, at the time of IIS it is not called self-hosting? what exactly does "self" means?

For me as a programmer, self-hosting means the application should be able to host itself, which means it must be able to listen to the web requests directly or it must run on its own process. Am I wrong? Please someone help me to understand the meaning of "self" in self-hosting.

Also, the image Microsoft uses to explain self-host is very confusing to me, as far as I know, IIS uses w3wp.exe to execute the application as:

[image]

The above image is good, w3wp is the process within that our app executes and IIS is the overall container.

But now, look at this image:

[image]

Here the application is the wrapper and Kestrel is within the application and the process (`dotnet.exe` / `application.exe`) is the wrapper containing Kestrel, why is it so?

For me, it should be

[image]

Why is my image different from Microsoft's image for self-hosting? Where am I missing the concept?

Comment: I believe, self-hosting essentially means that the application is able to spin up a web server to host itself and not depend on external web servers like IIS. ASP.NET core app runs its own Kestrel server implementation, the code for which is present in Program.cs file. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @VineetDesai yes, and the process name is same as the application name, means application.exe is the one which hosts compiled app, so, self hosting means hosting in its own process, isn't it? actually asp.net core is a console app which runs the web app within itself.

Comment: It's **Kestrel** - not "Kestral" ....

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to extend the concept:
**Hosted** is essentially an application (web app) exposed via a third party service that run a server (web server) for you.
**Self hosted** is the same application exposed via a server managed by you.

Sometimes, as correctly mention by Vineet, self hosted stands for an application with a *server* process exposing the application itself. Like Kestrel for Blazor.

IIS is not the discriminant for hosted or self-hosted, is just the base of the concept.

From my point of view when I use IIS Express integrated in Visual Studio debug, the application is self hosted and hosted at the same time.
Is *hosted* in IIS Express from a web server perspective and, at the same time, is *self hosted* from a service perspective.

Just for information: the **applicationName.exe** produced by the compiler for Blazor app is just a *launcher* based on Kestrel. Is a web server that launch the **applicationname.dll**

An example below from two total different application. The executable (you can open it with a binary editor) is the same.

[image]

Comment: @Nicoloa Biada , i don't think so, whatever you are saying , you are keeping the server admin in center, that is correct , but in programming term, where we just talk about programs, self hosting means an application is running in its own process, for example Asp.NET Core runs within apllicationName.exe, you can look at the diagram https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: applicationName.exe is just a wrapper. It's a Kestrel launcher for your applicationName.dll, it's just a webserver, your application is a DLL that need a web server to work. So in .net this kind of application aren't self hosted. In case you develop a C# socket application responding of http/https port I can  agree about "self hosting" concept.